# Does Math.Round() produce reliable hash values

Tags: c#, .net, hash, double, rounding

Is it save to compare the result of Math.Round(double,int) with `==` and use it for example as the key of a `HashSet<Double>` or a `GroupBy(d=>Math.Round(d,1))`?

In other words, are there any doubles x and y for which the following assertion will fail?

```
double x = ...;
double y = ...;
double xRound = Math.Round(x, 1);
double yRound = Math.Round(y, 1);

Debug.Assert(xRound==yRound || Math.Abs(xRound-yRound)>=0.1);
```

Let's say that I would like to group a list of doubles:

```
List<double> values = ...;
List<double> keys = values.GroupBy(d=>Math.Round(d,1)).Select(kv=>kv.Key).ToList();
```

Is there a chance that I would get a key with the value 0.100000000 and another key with the value 0.09999999999?

*(I tried parsing the disassembled net framework Math.cs source, but Round() eventually calls a native function.)*

Comment: Using a `double` as a key to a collection is always dubious. Is there a reason you have to use a floating point number as your key? If you only care about the first decimal place I would rather multiply by 10 then round and cast to a `int`.

Comment: I'd use `decimal`: `Decimal d = Math.Round((Decimal)x, 1);`

Comment: you may find this link useful jon Skeet explains round, personally I would not trust round in .net for a hash. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/977796/why-does-math-round2-5-return-2-instead-of-3-in-c

Comment: @Scott Using a double has the advantage that I can later use the numbers without remembering the conversion factor. For example if I have a distance in meter and want to group these distances to whole centimeters, I would prefer for the key to have the same unit as the values.

Comment: *Nothing* involving double is reliable. Consider using `decimal` everywhere, which is reproducible.

Comment: I really like this question. I would *hope* that anything that theoretically rounds to, say, `0.1` will result in `Math.Round(..., 1)` giving the exact same double that `0.1d` does... but does it?

Comment: @CodesInChaos Decimal is **[not a fixed point format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5069750/net-why-is-there-no-fixed-point-numeric-data-type-in-c)**, it is just a floating point format with more precision than double. Given these conceptual similarities between float, double and decimal, I presume it will have the same problems with Math.Round, if any. Do you have evidence to the contrary?

Comment: @HugoRune Decimal is a floating point format, but it is a *decimal* floating point format.

Comment: @Rawling I do not yet see how being a decimal floating point format will guarantee that decimal can be used safely as a hash situations, whereas Double cannot, an answer detailing that would be useful to me. Nevertheless I would very much like to clear first whether *double* exhibits this particular problem in regards to Math.Round. Are there any sample values that exhibit this problem?

Comment: By being a decimal floating point value, `decimal` can represent any real value rounded to any number of decimal places (within reason) *precisely*, and so we can reasonably expect that `decimal.Round` will return the expected value. On the other hand, `double` cannot even represent `0.1` precisely, and so it's reasonable to ask "does `double.Round(0.09, 1)` necessarily return the same imprecise `double` representation of `0.1` as `double.Round(0.11, 1)` does?".

Comment: I found [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832335/does-math-rounddouble-decimal-always-return-consistent-results) which asks something similar but uses `ToString("Nx")` rather than `GetHashCode()` as a measure of equality, and as far as I can tell the answer given reveals a flaw with `ToString` rather than with `Round`.

Comment: The brute force approach mentioned in that answer seems like a reasonable solution. I am currently running a program to try all possible values, however I may have to do some more optimisations so that it will finish in a reasonable time

Answer (score 1):

Generally, given the same starting value and the same operations, the same result would be obtained.

However, if you (for example) did:

```
double d1 = 10;
d1 /= 0.1;
double d2 = 25;
d2 /= 0.25;
```

then you may well find that `d1` and `d2` do not have the same value (because IEEE754 can represent `0.25` exactly but *not* `0.1`.

So, given that and the rather large number of issues people seem to have with floating point, I'd say your best bet would be to choose a *different* method of hashing.